# Client in java not receving the data, sent by a python server

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

So I am building a to-do app, that should remind the user of the tasks by location (when he's close it'll send all the tasks that are set to the location).

In the main screen of the app, I have a list view of all the locations the user added. I am saving them in the database as a json string.

The user log in's in the login activity screen, and everything works fine - the data is sent to the server, the server checks if the username and password are correct and sents an appropriate message.

Then, it creates an intent to move to the main screen of the app I described earlier. In the oncreate funciton, I create a listview, and pull the locations that belong to the user connected from the DB. But - the java client side for some reason, doesn't receive it.

I'll provide here my code and explain:

```
package com.example.yearprojectfinal;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private final static String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.218";

    private final static int PORT = 50001;

    private Socket socket;
    private String sendingStr = "";
    private String receivingStr = "";

    public SocketTask(String str1) {
        this.sendingStr = str1;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arrStrings)
    {
        try
        {
            this.socket = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
            send(this.sendingStr);
            receive();
            this.socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return this.receivingStr;
    }

    private void send(String sendingStr)
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStream outputStream = this.socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] bytes = sendingStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("sent");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }


    private void receive()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("trying to receive");
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1)
            {
                baos.write((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println("hello");
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            receivingStr = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            inputStream.close();
            Log.d("str received", receivingStr);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class I use to send data and receive data from the server. It works fine with everything else other than what I explained.
I use it with this function:

```
private String sendAddLocationDataToServer(String strToSend)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketTask send1 = new SocketTask(strToSend);
            String strReceived = send1.execute().get();
            return strReceived;
        }

        catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return "something went wrong with execution";
    }
```

The function creates a new SocketTask class, sends and receives the data.
Then returns the received data.

I call the function like so:

```
public ArrayList<Location> getLocationListForUser()
    {
        String dataStrToSend = "requesting location list," + connectedUsername;

        // send length header
        String resultStr = sendAddLocationDataToServer(
                String.format("%05d", activityName.length()) + activityName
                        + String.format("%05d", dataStrToSend.length()) + dataStrToSend);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Location>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<Location> locationsListByUsername = gson.fromJson(resultStr, listType);

        return locationsListByUsername;
    }
```

In the python side, everything works fine - i checked it, printed, logged, and it sends everything as needed.
But when it comes to the java side, the program seems to break when I try to receive a string, here (In the receive function of the SocketTask class):

```
int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1)
{
    baos.write((char) c);
}
```

It looks like the inputStream.read() function throws and exception somewhere in it. But I do not see anything in the logcat, except for:

2022-12-21 15:55:43.640 14239-14242/com.example.yearprojectfinal I/earprojectfina: Thread[3,tid=14242,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7a3c35e33a60,peer=0x13200238,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

2022-12-21 15:55:43.640 14239-14242/com.example.yearprojectfinal I/earprojectfina:

2022-12-21 15:55:43.696 14239-14242/com.example.yearprojectfinal I/earprojectfina: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

I have no idea of how to solve it, or how to troubleshoot it anymore.

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `String strReceived = send1.execute().get();` Not good. Do not use the .get() on an AsyncTask. Remove it. Change to `send1.execute();` . Then in onPostExecute handle the received string.

Comment: Tell exactly the value of the string that is sent.

Comment: I solved it by adding a socket timeout. Thanks.

Comment: The string that's sent is a json string...

Comment: Take a short string for this post and tell exactly what you send.

Comment: thank you so much, but I've already solved the issue with adding timeouts